# How to select a child from a parent div in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="x"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="c">
        <div class="d"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I call `$(".d").click(function(){`, how can I select div class .b? I want to do this relatively, without using the `.b` class name.

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach:

```
$('.module').on('click', '.button', function () {
    $('.other', this)...
});
```

Where:

- `.module` is the outer-most (wrapper) element of the page component,
- `.button` is the element within the component whose click actions you're listening to,
- `.other` is the element you're selecting within the click handler.

Notice how:

- event delegation is used,
- the query within the handler is local, restricted to the page component.

Also, notice how the other answers are hard-coding the element relationship in jQuery (those `parent()` and `sibling()` calls) which is **not a good approach**.

Comment: @alias51 My code is designed for re-usability. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I use the template above several times on the same page, so need to select it relatively otherwise all classes will be affected, not just those in the immediate parent.

Comment: @alias51 The `.button` and `.other` queries are local with regard to their corresponding `.module` wrapper. The code will work for multiple `.module`s on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".d").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().prev('div'); // or $(this).closest('.b'); 
});
```

**Updated after OP's comment**

[**fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Wg9P/)

```
$(".d").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().children().first();
});
```

Reference

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

[.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Comment: Downvote for read this "I want to do this relatively, without using the .b class name." you use class 'b'

Comment: @NikolaMitev see my answer see my answer there is no `.b`. i have given option of `closest()`

Comment: @NikolaMitev my answer was same but `parent()` was in comment.

Comment: How would this work if I had more than one div in the parent? Please see the update

Answer (score 0):

You have to find `parent` previous `sibling`

```
$(".d").click(function(){
     $(this).parent().prev();
})
```

if you want to set the third sibling before current parent simply append three times prev()
ex.

```
$(".d").click(function(){
         $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev();
 })
```

Comment: How would this work if I had more than one div in the parent? Please see the update

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not their relative positions will always stay the same.

If b is always going to be d's parent's previous sibling, you can select it with the following:

```
$('.d').on('click', function(){
    var b = $(this).parent().prev();
});
```

If b is always going to be d's parent's parent's first child:

```
$('.d').on('click', function(){
    var b = $(this).parent().parent().find(">:first-child");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(.d).click(function(){

$(this).parent().siblings('.b') //in this way
})
```

there are many ways for doing this for them you can refer to jquery website
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: How would this work if I had more than one div in the parent? Please see the update

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".d").click(function(){
    alert($('div[class="a"]').children(":first").text());
});
```

this will select the element with class b.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6TNDH/)

This will also work

```
$(".d").click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().parent().children(":first").text());
});
```

[Live Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/6TNDH/1/)

Even this

```
$(".d").click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().prev('div').text());
});
```

[Live Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/6TNDH/2/)